# Does Eurostar enforce any penalties for booking a throwaway return ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, eurostar

As outlined in a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44654/why-do-eurotunnel-do-cheaper-fares-for-shorter-trips), Eurostar charges less money for short-term return trips than it does for one-way trips. Assuming one only needs a one-way ticket to/from the UK and buys a throwaway return ticket, can they expect any issues later on?

I'm mostly interested in how it works in *practice*, not what it says in their T&C.

Comment: See [this part on Eurostar fares from the Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/London-to-Paris-by-train.htm#Fares) - it seems Eurostar sometimes sells cheap one-way tickets, sometimes changes its mind and adds the premium back in, changing again a year or so later...

Comment: @Gagravarr currently a throwaway return ticket is about 10 pounds cheaper.

Comment: Another related question here - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/what-is-the-common-practice-when-crossing-english-channel-la-manche-regardin - I've actually highlighted part with `will be liable` - time to switch to throw away payment cards for each transaction...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking in my travel history, I found that I travelled from Brussels to London in Jan 2015 on a throwaway return (23 pounds cheaper) without going back.

Never heard anything from Eurostar since, so given that the question is about **actual practice**, no, at least in Jan 2015 they weren't enforcing any penalties.

Comment: Did you travel with them again later with the same card and/or vehicle?

Comment: @Belle Yes.....