# Will I be able to board Le Shuttle for a second time without facing repercussions after not using the second half of a return ticket?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, legal, france

I've read various things about not using return legs being cheaper with airlines sometimes. I've found a similar thing with Le Shuttle, the train from Calais to Folkestone.

I am interested in buying two return tickets with Le Shuttle on two different weekends. Would not using the return leg void the second ticket or have any other possible consequences to my other return ticket (booked with the same credit card and with the same vehicle) I should consider?

As you can see on https://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/tickets/ an overnight return ticket is cheaper than a single or long stay ticket.

The website says just the following:

> +£30 Day trip & overnight - Ticket must be purchased as part of a 2 day return. Return must be completed by midnight (local time) on the second calendar day.

It [seems possible to not use the return part](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89878/does-eurostar-enforce-any-penalties-for-booking-a-throwaway-return-ticket), but I would like to know if I can come back with the same card (could change up the card perhaps) and the same car, in practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89878/does-eurostar-enforce-any-penalties-for-booking-a-throwaway-return-ticket

Comment: @JonathanReez I'd argue it is different because I am asking about my 'actual' return. I've seen some suggestions that they charge you extra to board the second time, but no actual proof. The body of your question suggests my question, but the answer does not answer it.

Comment: I'm all for actually marking it as a duplicate if we can get that bit answered in your question though.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in their terms do they suggest that they will "bar you from future travel" or "cancel any other reservations in your name".  I have also never heard of this happening, so I don't think that will be a problem.

What they do explicitly say, is that they will be entitled to chase you for the full fare of both journeys.

Will they do so in practice?  No idea.  But that is the consequence you are risking.